# How can I trigger this animation to start once in viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I trigger this animation to start once in viewport?

`<div class="monster"></div>`

```
.monster {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: -50px auto;
  background: url('/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/sprite1.png') left center;
  animation: play 2.8s steps(15);
  animation-iteration-count: 1
}

@keyframes play {
    100% { background-position: -3000px; }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "once in viewport"?

Comment: The best way to do this is to move the animation into a separate class and then add it when your element intersects the viewport (you can use an `IntersectionObserver` for that).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) in javascript to detect when the element is on screen, then trigger the class that plays the animation like this (I changed your animation values since you wouldn't see them in a SO snippet):

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.monster');
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  element.classList.toggle( 'animation', entries[0].isIntersecting );
});

observer.observe( element );
```

```css
.monster {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: black;
}
main {
  margin: 1000px auto;
}

@keyframes play {
    100% { background: red; }
}

.animation {
  animation: play 2.8s steps(15);
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.monster:after {
  position: fixed;
  content: 'Keep scrolling!';
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transition: opacity .4s;
}
.monster:not(.animation):after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="monster"></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe you can use a more traditional way.

```
/* If Item is in Viewport */
function isInViewport(item) {

    var bounding = item.getBoundingClientRect(),
        myElementHeight = item.offsetHeight,
        myElementWidth = item.offsetWidth;

    if(bounding.top >= -myElementHeight
        && bounding.left >= -myElementWidth
        && bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) + myElementWidth
        && bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) + myElementHeight) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Usage

```
var item = document.getElementsByClassName("monster");

if(isInViewport(item)) {
   item.classList.add("animation");
}
```

If you want to check it with scroll event

```
const monster = document.getElementsByClassName("monster");

/* Window Scrolling */
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){

   if(isInViewport(monster)) {
      monster.classList.add("animation"); 
   }

});
```